# Stripe expanding the Account object in BankAccountListOptions is not working while data.account is set

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I'm using Stripe.Net to fetch a customer's bank accounts. However, the account object is null despite `data.account` is passed to the Expand property as follows.

```
var serviceb = new BankAccountService();
var opts = new BankAccountListOptions {
      Expand = new List<string> {
        "data.account"
      }
   };
var lst = await serviceb.ListAsync(customerId, opts);
var firstBankAccount = lst.First();
```

`firstBankAccount.Account` and `firstBankAccount.AccountId` are null, which I'm unable to figure out what's wrong.

**Note: I've linked the customer's bank account through Plaid Link, `stripe_bank_access_token`, in Sandbox mode. Also, I'm using Stripe on test mode.**

```
      var options = new CustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Description = "User",
                Source = Source, // a tok_* which provided by Plaid through `PLAID/processor/stripe/bank_account_token/create` API
                Email = "a@a.com"
            };
   var service = new CustomerService();
   await service.CreateAsync(options);
```

Here is the bank account and the customer that was created on Stripe using the above code.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to expand `data.account`? `account` is only set for external bank accounts (that are used for payouts), not bank accounts that are used as payment methods.

Comment: @karbi Thank you for the comment. I thought the bank object is related to the current customer but as you mentioned, it is for external bank accounts, custom accounts. Actually, I was confused by the documentation.